# Python/Scapy - Sniff, & Store source IP address and source MAC address

Tags: python, scapy, packet-sniffers, sniffing

Trying to create a function that does the following:

1. Uses sniff() function to listen for traffic at the en0ps3 interface
2. Handle traffic picked up by the sniff() function
3. Store the source IP address and source MAC address.
4. If an IP address has already been stored, but a different MAC address is seen then the script should also store this additional MAC address
5. The user should see a list of hosts appear in the terminal while the script is running

(I have another separate sample script that generates ARP traffic for testing functionality)

Output I'm getting is below - can anyone confirm if its correct? I'm new, and struggling with Scapy to validate my work:

```
^CEther / ARP who has 192.168.1.10 says 192.168.1.1
Ether / ARP is at 10:11:12:ab:ab:ab says 192.168.1.10
Ether / ARP who has 192.168.1.11 says 192.168.1.2
Ether / ARP is at 10:11:12:bc:bc:bc says 192.168.1.11
Ether / ARP who has 192.168.1.12 says 192.168.1.3
Ether / ARP is at 10:11:12:cd:cd:cd says 192.168.1.12
Ether / ARP who has 192.168.1.13 says 192.168.1.4
Ether / ARP is at 10:11:12:de:de:de says 192.168.1.13
Ether / ARP who has 192.168.1.14 says 192.168.1.5
Ether / ARP is at 10:11:12:ef:ef:ef says 192.168.1.14
Ether / ARP who has 192.168.1.15 says 192.168.1.6
Ether / ARP is at 10:11:12:f0:f0:f0 says 192.168.1.15
Ether / ARP is at de:ad:be:ef:de:ad says 192.168.1.10
```

My code is

```
from scapy.all import *


ethernetHeader = Ether()
ipHeader = IP()
icmpHeader = ICMP()

pkt = ethernetHeader/ipHeader/icmpHeader ##filtering out ARP traffic with an op code of 2 or "is-at"


def filter_packets(packets):
  def packet_handler(pkt):
    packets.append(pkt)
    
  return packet_handler



def main():
  
  packets = []
  
  sniff(iface="enp0s3", prn=filter_packets(packets))
  
 
  for p in packets:
    print(p.summary(ipHeader))


main()
```